# Any keyboard shortcut for intelliJ to replace space with underscore in selected text?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

The way we can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to make text upper case or lower case; is there any shortcut to replace spaces with underscores with selected text in IntelliJ Idea?

Like: `HELLO WORLD` to `HELLO_WORLD`?

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation

Answer (score 6):

Use this unofficial plugin:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation

Installation:

- Apple + Comma
- Search for plugins
- Browse Repo
- Search for String Manipulation
- Click install

Comment: that's good. Thanks